# How to perform cross account provisioning using Ansible?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible, terraform, provisioning

I have run a Terraforms script to provision EKS cluster using cross-account provisioning. So I ran Terraform scripts on account 1 and EKS got created in account 2.

`assume_role` helps me achieve this:

```
provider "aws" {
  assume_role {
    role_arn     = var.role_arn
  }
}
```

Is there an equivalent of Terraform's `assume_role` in Ansible?

2. I need to run a playbook to install Calico on the EKS on account 2 - but I would like to run the playbook from inside a `null_resource` in the Terraform code above.

```
resource "aws_eks_cluster" "eks_for_account_2" {
...
}

resource "null_resource" "calico_provisioner" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "<command to install Calico on eks_for_account_2. \
                I would like this command to run on account 2.
                But on contrary to what I'm trying to achieve, this command gets executed on account 1 \
                (instead of getting executed on account 2)
                How to run this on account 2? Please advise>"
  }
}
```

I am not able to find any articles which explain this.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there an equivalent of Terraform's assume_role in Ansible?

The [`sts_assume_role:` task](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.10/collections/community/aws/sts_assume_role_module.html#examples) will do that, and it's *possible* that if you run that in a separate play, you can set the environment variables that the AWS tasks look for and not have to pass it around all the time (but be forewarned I haven't verified this works for all tasks)

```yaml
- name: assume role play
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
  - sts_assume_role:
      role_arn: etc etc
      role_session_name: etc-etc
    register: my_role_creds

- name: now run with those creds
  hosts: whatever-you-want
  environment:
    AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: '{{ hostvars.localhost.my_role_creds.sts_creds.access_key }}'
    AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: '{{ hostvars.localhost.my_role_creds.sts_creds.secret_key }}'
    AWS_SECURITY_TOKEN: '{{ hostvars.localhost.my_role_creds.sts_creds.session_token }}'
  tasks:
  - name: show who I am
    aws_caller_info:
```